# Not receiving mail from php contact form - Namecheap answer

Tags: php, forms, email, smtp, contacts

I'm just creating my website and not have major knowledge about write codes.
I've created a contact form in the web that connects to php to send the email. I 've used it once with an x hosting company, but now I'm with Namecheap and cannot receive the mails sent from the contact form. I've made this question to Namecheap support team, but I didn't understand how to apply the answer the give me to my current form. Please let me know how to make it works.

Thanks in advance... Here's the message I've sent to support, the html-php code and the Support answer.

--

I'm building a site with namecheap domain and host and created an email: creative@mydomain.co

And have a contact form in my site in php POST that allow the visitors make contact with me, sending the form to my email accounts (creative@mydomain.co and creative@gmail.com)

The problem is that I didn't receive the forms sent from the website neither my namecheap mail nor gmail account.

I have used the same form in another host-domain and works fine, but It doesn't works with namecheap. I want to know what can I do to make it works, because everytime someone fill the form and submit it, I receive the following email as a spam mail in creative@mydomain.co:

```
A message that you sent was rejected by the local scanning code that
checks incoming messages on this system. The following error was given:

"Relaying not permitted"

------ This is a copy of your message, including all the headers. ------

Received: from rdxvimy by server89.web-hosting.com with local (Exim 4.80.1)
(envelope-from <rdxvimy@server89.web-hosting.com>)
id 1W6Pqa-025POLD-IT
for creative@gmail.com; Thu, 23 Jan 2014 14:21:52 -0500
To: creative@gmail.com
Subject: Contact: Richard P
From: creative@gmail.com
Message-Id: <E1W6Pqa-025POLD-IT@server89.web-hosting.com>
Sender: <rdxvimy@server89.web-hosting.com>
Date: Thu, 23 Jan 2014 14:21:52 -0500

Name: Richard P

Tel: 2282922 

Mail: creative@gmail.com 

City: N/A

Activity: Designer

Comment: How can you help me to increase my brand?
```

--

I didnt receive this in my creative@mydomain.co account but in _mainaccount@mydomain.co

I send to you the html and php code:

### HTML

```
<div id="contact">
<div id="contactArea" style="height: 0px;">
<form action="contactForm.php" method="post">


<div id="info_contact">
<label for="author"></label>
<input id="name" class="rounded" type="text" aria-required="true" tabindex="1" size="12" onFocus="if (this.value=='Name:') this.value='';" value="Nombre:" name="name">
<label for="tel"></label>
<input id="tel" class="rounded" style="width:200px;" type="text" aria-required="true" tabindex="2" size="22" onFocus="if (this.value=='Tel:') this.value='';" value="Tel:" name="tel">
<label for="email"></label>
<input id="email" class="rounded" style="width:270px; margin-left:12px;" type="text" aria-required="true" tabindex="3" size="22" onFocus="if (this.value=='E-mail:') this.value='';" value="Mail:" name="email">

<label for="city"></label>
<input id="city" class="rounded" style="width:200px;" type="text" aria-required="true" tabindex="4" size="22" onFocus="if (this.value=='City:') this.value='';" value="City:" name="city">
<label for="actividad"></label>
<input id="actividad" class="rounded" style="width:270px; margin-left:12px;" type="text" aria-required="true" tabindex="5" size="22" onFocus="if (this.value=='Activity:') this.value='';" value="Activity:" name="activity">
</div>

<div id="comment">
<label for="comment"></label>
<textarea id="message" class="rounded" onfocus="clearDefault(this)" tabindex="6" rows="3" cols="2" name="message" style="resize: none;">How can you help me to increase my brand?</textarea>
<input id="submit" class="envoie" value="Send" type="submit" tabindex="7" name="envoyer">
</div>
</form>
```

### PHP

```
<?php


// Clean up the input values
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
$_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

$_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}

// Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
$name = $_POST["name"];
$tel= $_POST["tel"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$city= $_POST["city"];
$activity= $_POST["activity"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

// Test input values for errors
$errors = array();
if(strlen($name) < 2) {
if(!$name) {
$errors[] = "You must enter a name.";
} else {
$errors[] = "You must enter a name.";
}
}
if(strlen($tel) < 6) {
if(!$tel) {
$errors[] = "You must enter a telephone.";
} else {
$errors[] = "You must enter a telephone.";
}
}
if(!$email) {
$errors[] = "You must enter an email.";
} else if(!validEmail($email)) {
$errors[] = "You must enter an email.";
}
if(strlen($city) < 3) {
if(!$city) {
$errors[] = "You must enter a city.";
} else {
$errors[] = "You must enter a city.";
}
}
if(strlen($activity) < 3) {
if(!$activity) {
$errors[] = "You must enter an activity.";
} else {
$errors[] = "You must enter an activity.";
}
}
if(strlen($message) < 10) {
if(!$message) {
$errors[] = "Please write a valid message";
} else {
$errors[] = "Please write a valid message";
}
}

if ($errors) 
{ 
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=http://mydomain.co/index.html#quoteform">'; 
exit ("<span class='failure'>Please fill your form again, we founf the following errors<ul>". $errortext ."</ul></span>"); 
sleep(3); 
}

// Send the email
$to = "creative@mydomain.co, creative@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact: $name";
$message = "Name: $name 

Tel: $tel

Mail: $email 

City: $city

Activity: $activity

Comment: $message ";

$headers = "From: $email";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Exit with a success message

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://mydomain.co">';
exit;("<span class='success'>Thank you... your message has been sent succesfully... Now you'll be redirected to the main page</span>" );
sleep(3);

// A function that checks to see if
// an email is valid
function validEmail($email)
{
$isValid = true;
$atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
{
$isValid = false;
}
else
{
$domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
$local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
$localLen = strlen($local);
$domainLen = strlen($domain);
if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
{
// local part length exceeded
$isValid = false;
}
else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
{
// domain part length exceeded
$isValid = false;
}
else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
{
// local part starts or ends with '.'
$isValid = false;
}
else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
{
// local part has two consecutive dots
$isValid = false;
}
else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
{
// character not valid in domain part
$isValid = false;
}
else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
{
// domain part has two consecutive dots
$isValid = false;
}
else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
{
// character not valid in local part unless 
// local part is quoted
if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
{
$isValid = false;
}
}
if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
{
// domain not found in DNS
$isValid = false;
}
}
return $isValid;
}

?>
```

--

Thank you in advance for the support you can give me.
Regards

Support Sk.: Please let me check

Me: thank you

Support Sk.: As far as I can see you are using 3rd party email address in From field of your form. We disabled mail sending from email addresses that are not located on our hosting server. We took these measures for preventing SPAM sending through forums, contact forms and other scripts. It means that you cannot use a non-local e-mail address in the FROM field of your mailform.

Support Sk.: If you still want to use non-local e-mail address in your form, we can open 25 port for you account.

Me: Yes please, cause I really need it.

Support Sk.: In this case I need to complete the verification before I may assist you with the request. In order to verify your hosting account please provide me with the following information: Main domain name: Namecheap account username: cPanel username: Namecheap Support Pin. You can find it here: https://manage.www.namecheap.com/myaccount/modify-profile-supportsettings.aspx

Me: Ok, USERNAME: XXXXXX  CPanel User: rdxvimy    Support Pin: xxxx

Support Sk.: We have opened port 25 for you. Please note that in this case you should specify Gmail server instead of ours in your form

Me: Gmail server, so what should I write?

Support Sk.: You should specify the server on which rcreative@gmail.com is created

Me: Excuse me but I dont understand... creative@gmail.com is the email of the visitor who writes his email in the form of the website, so I can reply him after

Support Sk.: I'm sorry for confusion. You should use following settings in your form: Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com Gmail SMTP user name: Your full Gmail address

---

**So here it ends... I really appreciate any help you can provide me. Thank you**

Comment: Your support guy is basically telling you to send the mail via SMTP instead of though the local mail server. I would highly recommend using https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, check out the SMTP example in the examples folder.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, I'll see if can make it works

Answer (score 5):

I have recently come across this issue. After doing some digging, i learned that the from email when using namecheap must be from a domain that is currently hosted on namecheap servers. Hope this helps someone else out one day.

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/859/0/-from-field

Comment: After racking my brain for about 4hours, I stumbled on this solution and it worked. Even Namecheap support staff didn't know about it.

Comment: I've found if you need to use a 'from' address that doesn't match an available domain, the best fix is to set the From to a namecheap-hosted domain, and set the Reply-To to the from address you wanted. Then any replies to that email will be directed to the correct place.

Comment: I had to change the to email address to an email with the same TLD as the website because I was getting the error "relaying not permitted". It can in fact relay the message if you setup an email forwarder in the cPanel

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your SMTP settings per your conversation with the support rep. These are set in your PHP.INI

Comment: Ty, but I didn't have a php.ini and dont know how to apply the response of the support ref. Really appreciatte if you can give me a "for dummies" like guide